# Rails API consumed by Angularjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, rails-api

I want to integrate a front end framework like Angularjs into one of my apps. Having never done that before, I was wondering if it would best to create RESTful APIs for my app and then make Angular consume them. Or should I create a complete rails app and integrate Angularjs into it.

Comment: I'm doing the second way, just have /api dedicated to the api

Comment: yep, that's better because of you start a new app you have to figure out how to setup database, and even if you do, it will consume more resources to have 2 apps instead of one

Comment: @apneadiving, any reasons why to have api dedicated to the api only when I can use it with Angular?

Comment: I just say in my routes, /api is reserved for api. My frontend is full angular backed by this api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can completely create RESTful APIs and create a complete rails app. However, you can also create RESTful APIs and let the angular frontend consume it. The choice is yours. 
It can be a topic of discussion. If you have time to explore new technology then I would suggest Rails back end + angular front end. But again the choice if yours.